# Javers: Showing List Changes even when not changed

Tags: java, object, comparison, javers

I am comparing two objects (using Javers 3.9.4) which have a structure like below:
`MyClass` has a bunch of fields some of which are Objects with Lists.
The list Objects do show changes even when they are the same in both instances of objects.

```
class MyClass {
    String s1;
    Services services;
}

class Services {
    ServiceS1 serviceS1;
    ServiceS2 services2;
}

class ServiceS1 {
    String id;
    List devicesS1List;
}

class ServiceS1Devices {
    String id;
    String name;
    Date date;
}
```

I create objects like this

```
ServiceS1Devices sd1 = new ServiceS1Devices("1", "d1", 1-2);
ServiceS1Devices sd2 = new ServiceS1Devices("2", "d2", 1-2);
List devicesS1List = new ArrayList<>();
devicesS1List.add(sd1);
devicesS1List.add(sd1);
ServiceS1 serviceS1 = new ServiceS1();
serviceS1.setId("ss1");
serviceS1.setDevicesS1List(devicesS1List);
Services services = new Services();
services.setServiceS1(serviceS1);
services.setServiceS2(serviceS2);
MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
obj1.setS1("1");
obj1.setServices(services);
```

Create the exactly similar object with only one change like below:

```
MyClass obj2 = new MyClass();
obj2.setS1("2");
```

Everything else is the same, the `Services`, etc.
Then I do a compare:

```
Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers()
                             .withListCompareAlgorithm(LEVENSHTEIN_DISTANCE)
                             .build();
Diff diff = javers.compare(obj1, obj2);
```

It gives me following output:

```
changes - ListChange:3 ValueChange:1
```

Value Change 1 is expected, why is it showing as List changed too (not expected in this case)?

Answer (score -1):

You should not use bare `List`. It's discouraged since Java 1.6 — JaVers dosn't know what's inside and how to compare it.
Always use properly parameterized generics, for example: `List<Something>`

Comment: Not using a bare List, it is just an example. The List is a List<Something>